# Module abc, register method

Tags: python

I try to use abstract in python, I created base class and concrete class. After I write register method, it shows `Undefined variable from import: register`. I suppose register is only a method, which library I shall import?

concreteTest.py:

```
import baseTest

class concreteTest(baseTest):

    def __abcMethodTest__(self):
        print("I am in concrete class")

baseTest.register(concreteTest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Subclass:', issubclass(concreteTest, baseTest)
    print 'Instance:
```

baseTest.py:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod

class baseTest:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __abcMethodTest__(self):
        while False:
            yield None
```

Comment: please reindent your code from concreteTest.py, quite hard to read python without indentations!

Comment: @evuez done, I enhanced a little bit.

Comment: “Undefined variable from import: register” is not a Python error message. Where does that come from?

Comment: @poke from Eclipse Pyde plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a class called `baseTest` within a module called `baseTest`, so after importing the module `baseTest`, you would need to use `baseTest.baseTest` to access the class:

```
baseTest.baseTest.register(concreteTest)
```

Note that you don't even need to register `concreteTest` as a virtual subclass, since it's already an actual subclass.  The `register()` method is meant to register classes that don't actually derive from an abstract class you defined, but do fulfill the interface.

That said, it is unlikely that you routinely want to use abstract classes in Python.  They are useful in some special circumstances, but aren't used as the standard way of declaring interfaces.  See also the blog post [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Comment: The suggestions is really good. I shall not think Python as Java. But even I use baseTest.baseTest.register..., it has same error.

Comment: @user I edited the question, but the title is still not clear. Also I did highlight the error you said, but I am not sure if this is or it was part of your explanation...

Comment: @user84592 Are you using PyDev? If you are, ignore this message and try to run it anyway, it should work fine!

Comment: @evuez Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NSN\trainingAndProjects\python\PythonWorkspace\com.nsn.mme.juhani.exer\concreteTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    class concreteTest(baseTest):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Do I missing initialization?

Comment: @Sven Marnach Anyway, Python is not Java, I shall take serious that writing Python in python way. You point very good articles.

Comment: Now it is working after taking all suggestions by experts. from baseTest import baseTest
class concreteTest(baseTest):
    '''
    
    '''
 
    def __abcMethodTest__(self):
        print("I am in concrete class")


baseTest.register(concreteTest)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Subclass:', issubclass(concreteTest, baseTest)
    print 'Instance:', isinstance(concreteTest(), baseTest)